# how to get rid of these weird artifacts in my fluid sim?

Tags: fluid-simulation, artifacts

[image: most prominent in the top left of the image]

Theyre most prominent in the top left of the image. Ive tried increasing the resolution but that didnt seem to help.

Comment: What lighting are you using? Have you tested the reflection with a more simple object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

increase the roughness of the reflektion to sth over minmum.

i have no model to test. Play with the value a bit.

[image]